# How to change the IP address on each Heroku request?

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-scraping, dyno, quotaguard

So I'm web scraping Google and am pretty sure it's blocking my requests based on the IP address. I've deployed my app to Heroku (which has dynamic IP addresses when the dynos restart) and I've noticed that if the app is up, after 5 requests, they stop being able to scrape properly. If I restart the dyne, then I get another 5 requests before it stops being able to scrape. This leads me to believe the static IP address when the dyno is up is the issue. I looked into QuotaGuard Dynamic IP's (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguard) but I don't think that will work because Google seems to be https. Has anyone dynamically proxied their requests through different IPs on Heroku before (if so, what do you recommend using)? I'm working in a Node.js environment.

Comment: This is against Google's terms of service. Please respect the terms of service instead of trying to bypass whatever technical restrictions Google might have in place.

Comment: @Chris Lots of companies scrape google search results. I don't think it's that bad. If you have any suggestions as to how to route a request to a different IP though, it would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxies, there are tons of paid / free proxies. You can rotate the proxies on each requests. Do note that there are different types of proxies. DataCenter IPs, Residential IPs and the most expensive Mobile IPs.

Comment: So right now I'm simulating a Linux x86_64...if my actual client is a mobile device (and not a linux), then would I still have to use 'expensive Mobile IPs'? Do you have any recommendations of well-documented proxy integrations? Just as an FYI I'm using express for my POST and GET requests.

Comment: Using express though, how do you falsify the IP that you're sending it from? For example, I was looking at this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-proxy but it doesn't seem to have any documentation about how to actually use the proxy once you have it.